# Send Simple JSON Response Nodejs

Tags: node.js, response, httpresponse

I am trying to send a neat and easy to parse json response to a client app connected to my api. Previously, I have sent a response of this format:

```
{
"success": false,
"message": "All Items Fetched",
"cartItems": [
    {
        "_id": "5abca75f43b4c21ec482e96d",
        "title": "Apples",
        "price": 594,
        "quantity": 6,
        "prodId": "5aadb71792f47742d4e3749b",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "5abca75f43b4c21ec482e96e",
        "title": "Red and Mixed Grapes",
        "price": 645,
        "quantity": 5,
        "prodId": "5aac5dac664a9042a44bf787",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "5abca76143b4c21ec482e96f",
        "title": "AnanaB",
        "price": 445,
        "quantity": 5,
        "prodId": "5ab1c1a8044a584bdcad6e1d",
        "__v": 0
    }
 ]
}
```

but now, I want to send a response in this manner `6 * of Apples` for each of the array items, for brevity's sake.

I have tried this code:

```
let cart = await Cart.find({});
console.log('Checkout Cart:\t' + cart);

let cartArr = [cart];
console.log('Cart Arr:\t' + cartArr);

for (quantity, title in cart){
    console.log( quantity + 'x of' + title);
}
```

but it throws this error in the for loop:

```
SyntaxError: Invalid left-hand side in for-loop
at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
at Module._compile (module.js:599:28)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
at Module.require (module.js:579:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Workspace\AdminBootstrap\app.js:24:14)
at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:676:10)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

How do I loop through this array to get this output?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find returns an array of objects.

A cart will look like below

```js
var cart = [{
    "success": false,
    "message": "All Items Fetched",
    "cartItems": [{
            "_id": "5abca75f43b4c21ec482e96d",
            "title": "Apples",
            "price": 594,
            "quantity": 6,
            "prodId": "5aadb71792f47742d4e3749b",
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "_id": "5abca75f43b4c21ec482e96e",
            "title": "Red and Mixed Grapes",
            "price": 645,
            "quantity": 5,
            "prodId": "5aac5dac664a9042a44bf787",
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "_id": "5abca76143b4c21ec482e96f",
            "title": "AnanaB",
            "price": 445,
            "quantity": 5,
            "prodId": "5ab1c1a8044a584bdcad6e1d",
            "__v": 0
        }
    ]
}];

cart.forEach((data) => {
    for (var obj in data.cartItems) {
        console.log(data.cartItems[obj].quantity + ' x of ' + data.cartItems[obj].title);
    }
});
```

Comment: Destructuring was the key bro. It shows undefined x of undefined. How do I get the actual values and send them as a response?

Comment: @Andromeda If a cart is an object and you want to access 2 keys only no need of `ForIn`  loop. I have updated answer

Comment: Still undefined bro

Comment: @Andromeda check now Find returns an array of object, You have to write one more outerloop.

Comment: The code works here but on my terminal nothing is logged, where should I write the outerloop and is it possible to send this type of response? Thanks

Comment: print cart in console see what are you getting.

Comment: Your code works but only here, I don't know why it doesn't log on my terminal

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you expected... here's the way you could loop through...

> for(qty in obj.cartItems)   {
>   console.log(obj.cartItems[qty].quantity + ' of ' +
>   obj.cartItems[qty].title)   }

where *obj is the object response obtained from node.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `of` in your loop and use braces for object destructuring to work:

```
for (const {quantity, title} of cart) {
    console.log('%s of %s', quantity, title);
}
```

assumign, of course, that `cart` contains the array shown in your JSON as `cartItems`.

Comment: Thanks. This actually prints in my console. How do I send this as part of my json response?